# jQuery Pop-ups separate for $each?

Tags: jquery, popup, jquery-hover

Can anyone shed some light on why these popups show together as opposed to individually?

My intention is that the popup only shows when the the adjacent tweet is hovered over.

http://jsfiddle.net/P2FsR/

```
   var twitterURL = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23CM0655";
    function twitterSearch() { // Create the weather function   
        $.ajax({
        url: twitterURL, //http request string for the weather service
        dataType: "jsonp",                                                                                                  
        success: function(JSON) {                      // If successful parse the JSON data
            $('#twitterSearch').html("");
            $.each(JSON.results, function(i,tweet){
                    var tweeterID  = tweet.from_user_id;
                    var dateFormat = tweet.created_at;
                    var newDate    = dateFormat.replace('+0000', '');
                    var title      = 'title="Tweeted from"';
                    var id         = tweet.id;
                    var locData    = tweet.geo;
                    getCordsData(locData);

    $(function() {
    $('#twitterSearch li').hover(function(e) {
        $('div#pop-up').show();

    }, function() {
        $('div#pop-up').hide();
    });

    $('#twitterSearch').mousemove(function(e) {
        $("div#pop-up");
    });

});



                    $('#twitterSearch').append('<li id="tweet' + id + '" class="tweet"><img class="tweetImage" src="'+ tweet.profile_image_url +'" height="35" width="35" /> <a class="tweetLink" href="http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '" target="_blank">' + tweet.from_user + '</a> on the ' + newDate + ' <br /> tweeted<span id="tweetTextColor">: ' + tweet.text + tweet.geo +'</span></li><div id="pop-up"><p>' + tweet.from_user + '</p><div>');
            });
        //alert("Ajax text");
        setTimeout(twitterSearch, 10000);


        }
        }); // End of ajax
     } // End of function



    function getCordsData(data){
        if(data == null){
            data = "No location data found!";
            //$('#pop-up').append('<p>Cow</p>');
            //alert(data);
        }else{
            var long = data['coordinates'][0];
            var lat = data['coordinates'][1];
            $('#pop-up').html($('#pop-up').html() + "long:" + long + "<br />Lat:" + lat);
            //alert("long:" + long + "Lat:" + lat);
        }
    }

         twitterSearch();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` on hover of each li and [$(this).next()](http://jqapi.com/#p=next) to access each div#popup which is the next element are li

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/cDTWg/)

Hope this helps

PS: I just edited the hover function, hope you can do the same with the rest